# I have a lot of red lines for Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image: firebase]

I added Firebase on my app project and am trying to add authentication to my app, but it seems like it didn't work well.

I have a lot of red lines there and I don't understand what kinds of problem occurred. Would you help me to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Share your code and build.gradle(Module App)

Comment: You have to add BaseActivity to your code or you have to replace BaseActivity with AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, add this in build.gradle(Module App)

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
 .....
}
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kse.jackieapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added BaseActivity in your Project.
Follow these steps

1. Add BaseActivity
2. OR replace BaseActivity with AppCompactActivity
3. Add this in your build.gradle (App Module) - compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

Here is full demo - try to compare you project with this  [Firebase demo](https://github.com/Sanwal13/AllFirebaseDemo)

Let me know if there is an issue.

Comment: I added base activity, but had more problem. I'll upload the screen shot

Comment: "loading" in my baseactivity cannot be compiled.

Answer (score -1):

Please see all star marks.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        **GoogleSignInResult** result = **Auth**.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.**isSuccess**()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.**getSignInAccount**();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.**activity_google**);

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    showProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(**GoogleSignInActivity**.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    hideProgressDialog();
    if (user != null) {
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.**google_status_fmt**, user.getEmail()));
        mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.**firebase_status_fmt**, user.getUid()));

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.**signed_out**);
        mDetailTextView.setText(null);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```